# Chrome attempts to print a simple html document as 31K+ empty pages

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a simple html document (see - https://5fa3b1d135e99.htmlsave.net). When I try to print (cmd/ctrl+P) this document, chrome evaluate the print size as 31,776 pages:

[image: Chrome evaluate a simple page into tens of thousands of pages in print mode]

After some research, when removing the `gap` property from `.block-row`, it's fixed, but I have no idea what's the cause, plus - I do need the gap.

Any ideas?

In case the link gets expired, this is the output:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700');
@media print {
    * {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
    .block-row,
    .block-signature {
        break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
}
.page-header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin: 0 24px 24px;
    width: 100%;
}
.page-header > div {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.page-header > div > .a-logo-container,
.page-header > div > .other-logo-container {
    flex: 1;
}
.page-header > div > .a-logo-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.page-header .a-logo {
    display: block;
    width: 79px;
    height: 20px;
}
.page-header .other-logo-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.page-header .other-logo {
    background: none no-repeat center center / contain;
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 20px;
}
.page-header .other-logo-container {
    gap: 8px;
}
.page-header .other-logo-container h2 {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.page-footer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    gap: 8px;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 24px;
    color: #999;
}
.block-box {
    padding: 16px 24px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin: 16px 0;
}
.block-box .block-column {
    gap: 10px;
}
.block-row {
    display: flex;
    gap: 32px;
}
.block-row > * {
    flex: 1;
}
.block-row > * + * {
    margin: 16px;
}
.block-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.block-text,
.block-start-end-time {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 6px;
}
.block-inline-key-value {
    display: flex;
    gap: 16px;
}
.block-inline-key-value > strong {
    font-weight: 600;
}
.block-inline-title {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.block-container .label {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.block-title {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.block-item {
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
}
.block-radios {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 8px;
}
.block-radios .checkbox {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff inset;
}
.block-radios .checkbox[data-checked="true"] {
    background-color: #292929;
}
.block-radios > .block-container {
    display: flex;
}
.block-radios > .block-container > * {
    width: 100%;
}
.block-checkboxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 8px;
}
.block-checkboxes > .block-container {
    display: grid;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.block-checkboxes .checkbox {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.block-checkboxes .checkbox[data-checked="true"] {
    border-color: #292929;
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAHCAYAAADam2dgAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAABISURBVHgBfYzBDQAQEASvBCUoQUk6oRSlqIgSlgvigrPJfCaTJVIGwHcMfYKAsSylY46gLsfSTMGkKxBPEXt3cIRFDURoX74BA3ZgYkt9TZoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) no-repeat center center #292929;
}
.block-signature {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    gap: 12px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.block-signature .signature-title {
    border-top: 2px solid;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 50vw;
}
.block-signature .signature-container > img {
    transform: translateY(50%);
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <section class="blocks">
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-radios">
              <div class="block-inline-title">Radio</div>
              <div class="block-container">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-title">Main Header</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-radios">
              <div class="block-inline-title">Drop Down</div>
              <div class="block-container">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-text">
              <div class="block-inline-title">Short Text</div>
              <div class="block-container">
                  <div class="block-item">lorem ipsum</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-text">
              <div class="block-inline-title">Number</div>
              <div class="block-container">
                  <div class="block-item">100</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-row">
              <div class="block-signature">
                  <div class="signature-container"><strong>Tracey Kutch</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="signature-title">Patient Name</div>
              </div>
              <div class="block-signature">
                  <div class="signature-container">None</div>
                  <div class="signature-title">Signature</div>
              </div>
              <div class="block-signature">
                  <div class="signature-container"><strong>2020-11-04T00:00:00Z</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="signature-title">Date</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-start-end-time">
              <div class="block-inline-title">Time</div>
              <div class="block-container">
                  <div class="block-item">Invalid Date</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-title">TODO Image @Newbie012</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-title">TODO Chart @Newbie012</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-row"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-checkboxes">
              <div class="block-inline-title">Multiple Select (check)</div>
              <div class="block-container">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-radios">
              <div class="block-inline-title">Yes/No</div>
              <div class="block-container">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-title">Sub Header</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-text">
              <div class="block-inline-title">Long Text</div>
              <div class="block-container">
                  <div class="block-item">TypeScript supports JSX transpilation and code analysis. If you are unfamiliar with JSX here is an excerpt from the official website: JSX is an XML-like syntax extension to ECMAScript without any defined semantics. It's NOT intended
                      to be implemented by engines or browsers. It's NOT a proposal to incorporate JSX into the ECMAScript spec itself. It's intended to be used by various preprocessors (transpilers) to transform these tokens into standard ECMAScript.
                      The motivation behind JSX is to allow users to write HTML like views in JavaScript so that you can: Have the view Type Checked by the same code that is going to check your JavaScript Have the view be aware of the context it is
                      going to operate under (i.e. strengthen the controller-view connection in traditional MVC). Reuse JavaScript patterns for HTML maintenance e.g. Array.prototype.map, ?:, switch etc instead of creating new (and probably poorly typed)
                      alternatives. This decreases the chances of errors and increases the maintainability of your user interfaces. The main consumer of JSX at this point is ReactJS from facebook. This is the usage of JSX that we will discuss here.</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-row">
              <div class="block-signature">
                  <div class="signature-container"><strong>Eliya Local</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="signature-title">Employee Name</div>
              </div>
              <div class="block-signature">
                  <div class="signature-container">None</div>
                  <div class="signature-title">Signature</div>
              </div>
              <div class="block-signature">
                  <div class="signature-container"><strong>2020-11-04T00:00:00Z</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="signature-title">Date</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-row">
              <div class="block-signature">
                  <div class="signature-container"><strong>Signature</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="signature-title">Patient Name</div>
              </div>
              <div class="block-signature">
                  <div class="signature-container">None</div>
                  <div class="signature-title">Signature</div>
              </div>
              <div class="block-signature">
                  <div class="signature-container"><strong>2020-11-04T00:00:00Z</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="signature-title">Date</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-text">
              <div class="block-inline-title">Date</div>
              <div class="block-container">
                  <div class="block-item">12/Sa/1996</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-start-end-time">
              <div class="block-inline-title">Time</div>
              <div class="block-container">
                  <div class="block-item">Invalid Date</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-text">
              <div class="block-inline-title">Add Free Text</div>
              <div class="block-container">
                  <div class="block-item"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-title">TODO Chart @Newbie012</div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-text">
              <div class="block-inline-title">Blood Pressure</div>
              <div class="block-container">
                  <div class="block-item">100 / 90</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-row"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-row"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block-row">
          <div class="block-row"></div>
      </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `.block-row { display: flex; gap: 32px; }` is the culprit, no idea why... (probably worth a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) anyway)

Comment: Yes and no. There's something fishy with the spacing. When I tried to remove the gap and replace it with margins, it still behave incorrectly

Comment: Apparently you only need `column-gap` (from fast visually checking), and `row-gap` is the one who triggers this bug, so replace `gap` to `column-gap` and you should be fine.

Comment: @Kaiido I have additional forms that do need the `row-gap` (when there are multiple children inside a `block-row`). Therefore, both of them are needed.

Comment: Bless you for putting `31,776` in this question so that I could find the solution.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by @kaiido the culprit seems to be the empty `.block-row` with the `gap` property.

We encountered the same issue and posted a bug in Chrome see [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1161709).

Our solution was to remove the `gap` property when the container is empty.

In your case

```css
.block-row { display: flex; gap: 32px; }
.block-row:empty { gap: unset; }
```

Comment: Placing the updated issue here - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1161709

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any empty tags and was still getting this issue. So I just removed gap entirely when in print mode and that worked.

```
@media print {
    * {
        gap: 0 !important;
    }
}
```